# Convert while loop results into array

Tags: php, arrays

how to convert while loop results to array?

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo $rows['item']; 
}
```

then result into this array below:

```
$myArray = array("one", "two", "three","four","five","one","four");
```

Comment: $myArray[] = $rows['item'];

Comment: isn't `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` returning an array?

Comment: or look at [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: thnkyou splash58 .it works.
yes moffeltje. i need to compare some data into an array but not
mysql_fetch_assoc($result) becuase its not working. i need to count duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray=array();
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $myArray[]=$rows['item']; 
}
print_r($myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be done the way below including if you are looking for counting with pushing values:
    $y = array();
    $count = 0;
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        array_push($y , $rows['item']);
        $count ++;
    }